Enhancing turtle graphics in a custom tk window
I'm trying to use my own Tk window for my turtle interface so that I can add Tk widgets to my turtle program. It's a very simple program where you can draw with the turtle pen. However, I want to have a way to adjust the drawing speed, and I plan to do that with Tk sliders. However, before adding sliders, I notice that the turtle has a more erratic movement compared to without the custom Tk embedding. How can I optimize the movement of the turtle inside the Tk window?
Here is my entire program (for now, without any sliders):
import turtle as t
from tkinter import *


win = Tk()
canvas = t.ScrolledCanvas(win)
canvas.pack()
screen = t.TurtleScreen(canvas)
pen = t.RawTurtle(canvas)
move_scroll = Scale(win, from_=1, to=10, orient=HORIZONTAL)
turn_scroll = Scale(win, from_=1, to=30, orient=HORIZONTAL)
move_scroll.pack()
turn_scroll.pack()
screen.listen()

screen.onkey(lambda: pen.forward(move_scroll.get()), "w")
screen.onkey(lambda: pen.forward(move_scroll.get()), "Up")
screen.onkey(lambda: pen.backward(move_scroll.get()), "s")
screen.onkey(lambda: pen.backward(move_scroll.get()), "Down")
screen.onkey(lambda: pen.left(turn_scroll.get()), "a")
screen.onkey(lambda: pen.left(turn_scroll.get()), "Left")
screen.onkey(lambda: pen.right(turn_scroll.get()), "d")
screen.onkey(lambda: pen.right(turn_scroll.get()), "Right")
screen.onkey(lambda: pen.penup() if pen.isdown() else pen.pendown(), "p")


screen.mainloop()


Seems basically the same either way my machine (Ubuntu 22.04, Framework 11, typical processor for a 4 year old computer and 32 GB memory). If you're doing real-time speed adjustment, I'd suggest this approach.

Oh, that's strange because I'm on a new Windows 11 and the graphics seems fine with Tk or turtle individually, but it's blocky when I combine them. As for the latter part, no I am not doing real-time adjustment during the drawing process but rather as a tool to customize how the turtle draws because all the drawing is manual.

Even so, most turtle-based rendering/update loop stuff is very restrictive, non-performant and fussy, so if you're doing just about anything other than drawing simple shapes, you'll most likely want to take over the update loop. Can't hurt to try it to see if it fixes your sluggish perf here.

So you're saying, I should probably change the update system to refresh only when an action occurs? That's roughly what I got from that post, correct me if you mean otherwise.

Sort of--it depends on what you're doing. The internal turtle loop is highly nerfed to be implicit and beginner-friendly, but if you're doing anything interesting (where "interesting" is defined as anything that involves granular control beyond setting the turtle speed from 1-9, e.g. controlling the framerate, responding to input/sliders, moving multiple turtles simultaneously, etc), then you'll probably want to disable tracer and do your updates explicitly where/when you need them.

Right, currently I don't have anything "interesting" planned, but I definitely want to add more to the system than just what I've got; however, I'm not sure if anything really needs to involve granularity here. But I'll try it out and see the results--- I don't see any potential backward progress because no events are simultaneous.

continue this discussion in chat
